# Mongoose pre save hook: next() is called before field assignment

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Before diving into this one, I'm aware that next() will be called before async operations have finished running. But a simple object property assignment is not asynchronous and I'm not sure why next() is being called before this assignment. Note also that I've tried multiple versions of this.

I'm trying to set a `weekNum` property on my model only when a new document is created. Here's my current code:

```
Schema.pre('save', async function (next) {
  if (this.isNew) {
    await this.constructor.countDocuments({ type: `${this.type}` }, function (err, count) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
      } else {
        this.weekNum = count + 1;
        console.log(this.weekNum); // this returns the correct variable in my console
        next(); // when I request the created document, it has no weekNum property. 
      }
    });
  }
  else {
    next();
  }
});
```

I've also tried moving the next() outside of and immediately after the await statement. However, next() never seems to wait for this operation to complete. How can I make sure we don't save the document before the field has been updated?

Answer (score 1):

I got it -- turns out I was mixing async/await with a callback. Here is one correct way to do it:

```
Schema.pre('save', async function (next) {
  try {
    if (this.isNew) {
      const count = await this.constructor.countDocuments({ type: `${this.type}` })
      this.weekNum = count + 1;
      console.log(this.weekNum);
      next();
    }
    else {
      next();
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
    next();
  }
});
```